# Batch environment variable expansion when variable ends with a backslash?

Tags: windows-vista, command-line, environment-variables

I just need to ask if this is expected behaviour, it sure surprised me.

We have a batch file that copies some files from a sub-directory of where it is located, to another location on every developers machine. Since for some developers, this target directory differs from the rest, we've set a user environment variable, and used that in the batch file.

This is a sample line from the batch file:

```
ROBOCOPY Staging\*.* "%DISTRIBUTE_TARGET%" *.* /IS
```

This failed on one machine, and after some experimentation, it dawned on me that on this machine, the variable had a trailing backslash as part of the variable content.

On most machines (in fact, all the other machines, where it worked), the variable looked like this:

```
DISTRIBUTE_TARGET=C:\Some\Directory
```

but on this machine, it was:

```
DISTRIBUTE_TARGET=C:\Some\Directory\
```

notice the added backslash there.

The error message given by ROBOCOPY was that there was something wrong with the second parameter, but it seemed to think that everything from the start of that variable, and to the end of the line, was all in the 2nd parameter.

Ie. the error message looked like this:

> `Error in second parameter: "C:\Some\Directory\" *.* /IS"`

What I assume happened is that the backslash "escaped" the quote character, which removed its meaning as "end of quoted parameter", and thus the rest of the line was just grabbed as part of the argument.

Is this expected behavior? Does this mean that variables with a trailing backslash, for whatever reason or purpose, just cannot be safely used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [article](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html):

> If either the source or destination
>   are a "quoted long foldername" do not
>   include a trailing backslash as this
>   will be treated as an escape
>   character, i.e. "C:\some path\" will
>   fail but "C:\some path\\" or "C:\some
>   path" will work.

This is a problem specific to robocopy. I would even go as far as to call it a bug.

You have no other solution but to add code to your batch file that will check and delete a backslash from the end of the source and destination.

Comment: Wrong. This is a bug-sold-as-feature in Windows shell variable expansion. Why is this marked as answer!?

Comment: @DanielDinnyes: My explanation above is actually correct, since the analysis of the command-line is done by robocopy and not by Windows. Windows uses the back-slash as the directory separator and doesn't have an escape-character. The analysis routine of robocopy was probably taken from Linux and sees an escape-character where there is none, so treats the `\"` as `"` that is included in the string. So it continues the string up to the next `"`, gets confused, and generates an error.

Comment: As the above was written in 2010, this problem might not still exist today in robocopy.

Comment: Your explanation is actually not correct. The correct answer is below from @Kevin. This has nothing to do with robocopy. The shell script the OP wrote has the problem, as robocopy receives `"C:\Some\Directory\" *.* /IS"` as second argument from the shell. It is not the bug in robocopy that the second string is not recognized as a valid path.

Comment: Here running Windows 7, have a shell script which does this-and-that, but not even using robocopy, and still have the issue as of 2013.

Comment: @DanielDinnyes: Go into a cmd and issue `dir "c:\anyfolder\"`. This doesn't give an error since the '\"' is taken as 2 characters and is NOT incorporated as part of the string. According to Kevin `\"` is (2*0+1) backslashes and should produce "n backslashes followed by a quotation mark", meaning just the `"`. The fact that there is an error proves that robocopy doesn't use the result of CommandLineToArgvW and does its own argument-decoding. [I prefer not to continue further this discussion.]

Comment: @harrymc, my apologies, i am late a few months with my response. :) But anyway... Do not try with the `dir` command, as it is not an executable. Try starting an *.exe file, passing some arguments where the 1st is like _"c:\folder\"_. Windows screws this up when it is passing the arguments to the new process...

Answer (score 5):

Indeed this is not specific to robocopy, but rather the [CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Windows API function.

> CommandLineToArgvW has a special interpretation of backslash characters when they are followed by a quotation mark character ("), as follows:
>
> 2n backslashes followed by a quotation mark produce n backslashes followed by a quotation mark.
>
> (2n) + 1 backslashes followed by a quotation mark again produce n backslashes followed by a quotation mark.
>
> n backslashes not followed by a quotation mark simply produce n backslashes.

The same rules are described in [Parsing C++ Command-Line Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx)

A workaround is to append `.` to everything you know is a directory (e.g. `"C:\Program Files\."`)

Comment: I would add `\.` to the end instead. Has the same effect, but it is less confusing, therefore error prone. Having a `.` at the end of directory name is stripped of during file system navigation and operations, but it could cause problems if some program you pass it to tries to do something with it without being aware of the dot-stripping done by Windows. This stuff is arcane!

Comment: Be careful: `\.` is not the same as `\\.`. (The latter is interpreted as an invalid UNC path)